# Create custom workflow map in Win Forms or MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, workflow

We have a Management information system that is due to be upgraded/rewritten using asp.net MVC3 or WinForms using .NET 4 and SOA.

Within the site we will need to include a workflow map which is in the curent site, I could re-use the pages that are already there but I was just wondering... does anyone know of any technnologies, methodologies that are available to do this in MVC/WinForms .Net 4

Here is an example of how the current workflow looks
[image: Custom workflow]

I have trawled google and each search I put in directs me to the Workflow Foundation technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really neat and flexible way to link elements together which can be used as a workflow.

[JS Plumb](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html)